# Get nth element from the page with XmlArrow?

Tags: haskell, arrows, hxt

Following this [page scraping tutorial](http://adit.io/posts/2012-03-10-building_a_concurrent_web_scraper_with_haskell.html) the author gets a collection of all images on the page as follows:

```
css :: ArrowXml a => String -> a XmlTree XmlTree
css tag = multi (hasName tag)

images tree = tree >>> css "img" >>> getAttrValue "src"
```

How can I only get, say, the 2nd image on the page? I couldn't find any sort of function like  `getElementAt :: Int -> blah` in the [XmlArrow docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/latest/doc/html/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlArrow.html#v%3agetAttrValue).

Thanks!

Comment: Cool article! I wonder how HXT handles malformed html?

Comment: It seems like it handles it fine when supplied with `withParseHTML` option... http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/latest/doc/html/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlState.html#v:withParseHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions for manipulating lists of elements can be found in the [ArrowList](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.3.1.1/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html#t%3aArrowList) type-class.

In this particular case, you can use the `>>.` operator to transform the result list using ordinary list functions.

```
nthImage n tree = images tree >>. (take 1 . drop n)
```